# Assigning jQuery Data Property

Tags: jquery

Good morning folks, just wanted to check if someone can help me with the jQuery data property in a script.

Basically I am using this plugin - https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.imgpreload

Its a simple preload plugin.

What I am trying to do is one line 66 just after the src attribute is assigned to the image object - I am trying to put the width and height attribute of that image in its data but its not working.

I am inserting this just after line 66

```
$.data(this, 'dimensions', { 'width': img.width, 'height': img.height });
```

Its giving me a "indefinite recursion" error in the query.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(img).data('dimensions', { 'width': img.width, 'height': img.height });
```

**Edit:**
I guess you can try your syntax again, only try using `img` instead of `this`.

Comment: Although I'm not sure if you can store objects using `$.data()`. I know for a fact than you _can_ using `$(obj).data()`.

Comment: thanks a lot - I did it with $.data(img, 'dimensions', { 'width': img.width, 'height': img.height });  - seems like an issue with the plugin only - can't seem to load the image dimensions after preload... will post issue on github... thanks a lot again!